Formatting the currency to show Rs. instead of indian rupee simbol in java
In this question I am doing, I am asked to convert an amount into the Indian numbering format and the expected output is - India: Rs.12,324.13. However, even though I converted into the Indian numbering format, the answer I got is - India: ₹12,324.13.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double money = input.nextDouble();
        NumberFormat currencyFormat2 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
        String formatted2 = currencyFormat2.format(money);
        System.out.println("India: " + formatted2);
   

The output I get from the above code is - India: ₹12,324.13
The expected output is - India: Rs.12,324.13
I have tried the above method, but the website would not accept the output when the rupee symbol is used. Therefore I need to remove the rupee symbol and put Rs. instead. How do I fix this?

Use simple number format, not currency. you can then display it by System.out.println("India: Rs" + formatted2);.
